# Embed Vimeo video with the HTML5 video element and without iframe

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo

I'm trying to embed a Vimeo video into a webpage, using the HTML5 video element, despite Vimeo's embed code using an iframe. I want to use the video element so that I can create a fully responsive webpage including videos, but I'm having trouble without using HTML5. I've tried a couple of tools, most successfully using fitvidsjs, but the responsiveness isn't 100% (black bars etc..).

Is it at all possible to use the HTML5 video element with a Vimeo video (i.e. without an iframe)? Could the Vimeo API help me achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use below code for display in html 5

```html
<object width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"/>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <embed width="640" height="360" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
```

Comment: The full screen option does not seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo actively prevents this. It's technically impossible.